# TSQL Inside Dynamic Query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures, for-xml-path

I am in the process of building out a dynamic sql query but I am running into an issue. I need to create sub selects within this query and output their results as XML as well since there is more than one value returned.

```
-- Open our primary select
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT('

    -- Begin the first sub select of primary fields
    SELECT @SQL += 'SELECT '

        -- Go through the primary fields temp table and print out the column names
        SELECT @SQL += (
            SELECT f.alias + ', ' 
            FROM @primaryFields AS f
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
        -- Remove the trailing comma from the last field
        SELECT @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) -1) + ' '

        -- Begin the select statement
        SELECT @SQL += ' FROM View_BS_Render_Dashboard as db '

        -- Create our WHERE Clause
        SELECT @SQL += 'WHERE '

        -- Test Data
        SELECT @SQL += 'db.initiativeCreatorEmpID = @initCreator '

        SELECT @SQL += 'FOR XML PATH(''primary''), ELEMENTS, ROOT(''primaryFields'')'

    SELECT @SQL += ')'

-- Print the closing XML data
SELECT @SQL += 'FOR XML PATH(''data''), ELEMENTS, ROOT(''root'')'

-- Execute the SP
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@initCreator varchar(12)', @initCreator='1234'
```

The issue I am running into is with the INNER `FOR XML`. It is causing all of the fields to be printed out as a string instead of XML.

Here is the output:

```
<root>
  <data>&lt;primaryFields&gt;&lt;primary&gt;&lt;initiativeTitle&gt;Test&lt;/initiativeTitle&gt;&lt;initiativeDescriptionPreview&gt;Test Desc&lt;/initiativeDescriptionPreview&gt;</data>
</root>
```

As you can see, the XML tags are working fine on the outer select but it isn't working on the inner select. If I comment out the outer and just use the inner select, those fields then display fine (as xml).

What am I missing here? I will have 3-4 sub selects in total inside the main root/data node so I need to be able to nest the XML.

Comment: try option `FOR XML ... , TYPE` for inner for xml

Comment: @IvanStarostin its those small details :/. I appreciate it, that worked.

Comment: Is there any reason why you do this with dynamic SQL? The only reason I see is the `FROM @primaryFields` which might be done in another way... Especially if you need to add more columns and nestings this is quite some pain in the neck...